# Error when trying to get PDO execute to work

Tags: php, sql, pdo, binding, execute

This works, I paste the code from what is echoed on the print_r into the execute statement and everything is fine.

```
$search_items = array();
for ($x = 0; $x < $search_parts_count; $x++) {
     $search_items[] = "':search$x' => '%$search_parts[$x]%'";
}
print_r(implode(",", $search_items));

$stmt->execute(array(':search0' => '%cure%',':search1' => '%cancer%',':search2' => '%help%',':search3' => '%ongoing%'));
```

but when I do this:

```
$stmt->execute($search_items);
```

I get:

> Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens'

No idea what I am doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the statement:

```
$sql_string = 'SELECT area, file_name, title FROM meta_details WHERE' . $search_guts;
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql_string);
```

and it is being built like this:

```
$search_guts = '(';

    for ($x = 0; $x < $search_parts_count; $x++) {
        $search_guts .= 'title LIKE :search' . $x;
         if ($search_parts_count - 1 != $x){$search_guts .= ' OR ';}
        };

    $search_guts .= ') OR (';   

    for ($x = 0; $x < $search_parts_count; $x++) {
        $search_guts .= 'description LIKE :search' . $x;
         if ($search_parts_count - 1 != $x){$search_guts .= ' OR ';}
        };          
        $search_guts .= ')';
```

Thanks!

Comment: Would you like to show us the actual query you are trying to fit parameters into please

Comment: No! In the question so we can actually read it please

Comment: Assume there is a `prepare` line somewhere in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When building `$search_items`...

```
$search_items[] = "':search$x' => '%$search_parts[$x]%'";
```

You are creating an item with value `"':search$x' => '%$search_parts[$x]%'"` and not an entry for `:search$x`.  You should be setting up like...

```
$search_items[":search$x"] = "%{$search_parts[$x]}%";
```